# Crazy jquery selector behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I am using jquery 1.8 and I am using this peace of code:

```
jQuery('body.fb_tab-resizable:not(.fb_tab-processed)').each(function () {
      jQuery(this).addClass('fb_tab-processed');
      if (typeof(FB) == 'undefined') {
        // FB not yet initialized.
        jQuery(document).bind('fb_init', FB_Tab.setAutoResize);
      }
      else {
        // FB already initialized.
        FB_Tab.setAutoResize();
      }
      jQuery(document).bind('fb_init', FB_Tab.setAutoResize);
    });
```

it doesnt work, so I did a console.log of:

```
jQuery('body.fb_tab-resizable:not(.fb_tab-processed)')
```

this gives an empty result '[ ]'.

But when I do:

```
jQuery('body.fb_tab-resizable:not(.fb_tab-processed)').addClass('fb_tab-processed');
```

the class is added to the body and everything works.

Can anyone tell me something about this behaviour ?

you can find a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ettun/3/

**Edit: It does seem to work in JSFiddle, but not on my website, I'll try to update my code in fiddle

Comment: Do you have some HTML to test?

Comment: Not really, I will try te get something up

Comment: [Works just fine for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/ettun/2/) Do you have the code in a document.ready event?